# JavaFX, problemas al actualizar graphics de button

Tags: java, javafx

estoy realizando un juego de encontrar las parejas y me ha surgido un problema que llevo horas sin saber el porque ocurre, tengo el presentimiento que será una tontería pero no logro verlo. **Os comento el problema, lanzo un método que debería actualizarme el graphics de un botón y si no me cumple una condición en un método posterior se me restablece, la cosa está que no me actualiza el graphics**. Os detallo:

1) Al pulsar una tecla lanzo el metodo pulsaCasilla() el cual me cambia la imagen que tiene inicialmente el botón por la que se supone que hay detrás, la que contiene el objeto "Casilla".
Después realiza una rotación y envia el objeto casilla a otro método, comparaCasillas().

```
private void pulsaCasilla(ActionEvent event)
   {
       Button obj = (Button)event.getSource();

       for(Casilla c:casillas)
       {
           if(c.getButton().getId() == obj.getId())
           {   
               String path = c.getRuta();
               URL linkImg = getClass().getResource(path);
               System.out.println("RUTA IMG : " + c.getRuta());
               System.out.println(linkImg.toString());
               Image img = new Image(linkImg.toString() , ancho, alto, false, true);
               c.getButton().setGraphic(new ImageView(img));


               System.out.println(c.getButton().getId());
               System.out.println(obj.getId());
               System.out.println("ENTRA");

               RotateTransition rotarBoton = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(1) , c.getButton());
               rotarBoton.setAxis(new Point3D(0,1,0));
               rotarBoton.setFromAngle(0);
               rotarBoton.setToAngle(360);
               System.out.println("Inicia rotación");
               rotarBoton.play();


               comparaCasillas(c);

               return;
           }
       }
   }
```

2)El método comparaCasillas() agrega las "Casillas" a un arrayList y cuando el arrayList tiene 2 almacenadas las trata. Si el nombre es igual me cambia el valor de unas etiquetas para almacenar el marcador. Si no es igual me restablece en ambas la imagen de inicio. Después limpia el arrayList.

```
private void comparaCasillas (Casilla c) 
   {
       String name1 ="";
       String name2 ="";
       comparador.add(c);
       c.getButton().setDisable(true); 
       if(comparador.size()==2)
       {
           System.out.println("Entra en el comparador");
           name1 = comparador.get(0).getName();
           name2 = comparador.get(1).getName();

           if(name1.equalsIgnoreCase(name2))
           {
               System.out.println("Se ha producido un acierto");

                //Restamos descubiertas y añadimos cubiertas.
               descubiertas ++;
               cubiertas --;
               lv_Cubiertas.setText(""+cubiertas);
               lv_Descubiertas.setText(""+descubiertas);
           }
           if(!name1.equalsIgnoreCase(name2))
           {   
               System.out.println("Has fallado");
               comparador.get(0).getButton().setDisable(false);
               comparador.get(1).getButton().setDisable(false);
               System.out.println("Ejecuta el poner las imagenes a la anterior");
               imagenInicio(comparador.get(0).getButton());
               imagenInicio(comparador.get(1).getButton());
           }

           movimientos ++;
           lv_movimientos.setText(""+movimientos);

           System.out.println("//////////////////////");
           comparador.clear();

       }

   }
```

**El problema que tengo es el siguiente**, cuando realizo el primer click en un botón me cambia la imagen sin problemas y sigue el curso normal. Pero cuando hago click en el segundo realiza todo excepto el cambio de imagen, la ruta se pasa bien, pero es como si resolviese el "false" directamente, pero he probado a colocar un Thread.sleep() antes de llamar al método que estable la imagen inicial y nada. Además, la salida de consola de los prints que he puesto sigue el curso...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mi sugerencia y ademas es una buena practica, es cuando actualizas el hilo gráfico lo mejor es separar los otros procesos graficos que requieran hacer alguna acción, puedes usar Platform.runLater(new Runnable() .... lee un poco al respecto.

Comment: Vero, Igual deberías de checar [SwingUtilities](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml)